# ExtJS add custom event to body

Tags: events, extjs, custom-event

is to possible to attach custom events to the document's body? I wanna implement a simple message bus. I did it many times with jQuery, but not sure how to do it in ExtJS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to attach the event to the body or any DOM element, I would rather attach them to a dedicated object.

Like :

```
MyApp.MessageBus = Ext.extend(Ext.util.Observable, {

  // I don't think it's necessary to declare all events
  events : {
    sayHello : true
  }


});

MsgBus = new MyApp.MessageBus();
```

And, somewhere in your code :

```
MsgBus.on('sayHello', function(who) { alert("Hello, " + who); });
```

And, on another place :

```
MsgBus.fireEvent('sayHello', 'innerJL');
```

Comment: but in this case I have to inject the message bus into each component of my app. When I fire a custom event through the document's body, I can attach listener to it in any place easily. It's all about less coupled components.

Comment: If you make the message bus a singleton then it would be exactly the same amount of code as firing something on document.body, but with the added benefit that the message bus could be extended with other useful behavior. I would highly recommend this approach over attaching stuff to the document.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Drasill, and there are many examples in the Ext community for creating simple bus implementations based on Observable.  See [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?42942-Poor-man-s-Ext.ux.MsgBus&p=203156) and [here](http://blog.extjs.eu/plugins/ext-ux-msgbus-plugin/) for starters.

Answer (score 1):

Putting it on the document itself is problematic in terms of firing custom events. It can be done -- you would just need to make a class which extended `Ext.util.Observable` as your representation of the result of `Ext.getDoc`.

But you can bubble up events by adding to the Observables you already have [`enableBubble : ['foo', 'bar']`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Observable-more.html#method-Ext.util.Observable-enableBubble). That means you do `fireEvent('foo')` on any child Observable and it'll bubble up to the top where your listener is.